# GeoServer WFS - Casting a property to Integer for sorting

Tags: geoserver, wfs, sorting, integer

I have a WFS query string that ends with:

`&SORTBY=am_subtype%20DESC`

This works but `am_subtype` is a string, so it does not sort the way I'd like it to.   Can I cast `am_subtype` to an Integer somehow for the purpose of sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a possibility, WFS provides no type mutation of any sort: it's completely driven by the XML schema it exposes in DescribeFeatureType, every other request has to abide to it.
You'll have to perform the casting somewhere else, e.g., at the data source level for example (if it's a database, you can try using a SQL View).